# What is a good resource to understand maven

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-3, archetypes

I am not entirely new to the maven world but i have never taken couple of hours to actually sit down and understand what maven is all about. Whenever anything needed to be done, I trusted google as a source, tried stuff and when it worked I moved on.

I am looking for an online resource that will help me understand the whole maven architecture an an overview. For example, what are archetypes. I understand that 2 to 3 hours is not enough to understand everything but I want to know enough to be able to understand bits and pieces that come handy in day to day work. So, not looking for a maven book.

Github projects like [these](https://github.com/smanek/java-webapp-archetype) are great because I can mess around with code.

Answer (score 3):

To really understand what you seem to want to understand about Maven, you're going to have to do some reading. You can't just pick it up from looking at projects. It would be kind of like trying to learn to be a chef by going to a restaurant and looking at all the finished plates. You might get some useful ideas, but you'll never really be able to reason about why/how something works or doesn't work because you just won't have the full picture. Try the [Sonatype reference](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/). It's very well written as a reference guide. It should help you get the "big picture" you're looking for, and it's also useful for looking up the details of specific things when you need them.

**Update:** Almost forgot about [Sonatype's cookbook](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mcookbook/reference/). It's pretty basic, but more task-oriented, like you might want.

Comment: I've came across that before and yeah it is very detailed and does explain the facts, however, I thought it lacked a practical real life scenario to aid each topic. I will go through this though. thanks

Comment: Added another link to my answer. As with anything in software development, real-life applications vary so widely that you really have to start working with it to even know what questions to ask. There's no one resource that will have exactly what you're looking for, except maybe the internet as a whole. If come up with a particular topic (more fine-grained than just "Maven") that you're curious about or need help with, try formulating a more specific question